# Android, incomplete input from barcode scanner when virtual keyboard is enabled

Tags: java, android, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use a `KDC200 Bluetooth barcode scanner` with my android app, but I am running into issues when I have the virtual keyboard enabled(I think the virtual keyboard is the same as "softkey"? The android device is a Samsung Note 5). It seems there is some sort of interference where the scanner input gets cut off. For instance, instead of receiving `1234567890` in full, I might only receive `1234567` or `123456789` instead. When I disable the virtual keyboard through settings, I get the full input. This isn't just in my app, it happens with all of the apps I have used the scanner with.

I see a lot of questions asking about the virtual keyboard not showing when the scanner is connected, but so far nothing about incomplete input.

Is there a way to enable both the Bluetooth scanner and virtual keyboard to be enabled at the same time?

Otherwise, if the virtual keyboard must be disabled to receive the input in full from the Bluetooth scanner, then is there a way to programmatically enable and disable it when an `EditText` input is focused?

If the virtual keyboard must be disabled and I cannot programmatically enable and disable it, then is my only option to create my own keyboard with buttons? This seems like a last resort I think. It doesn't need to be a full keyboard, but just A-Z, 0-9, backspace, enter, and a period. Is there perhaps a better way? Maybe a library exists already?

I am currently using an app similar to what I am trying to build and it appears they have either made their own keyboard input or are using an external library, I'm not sure which. The keyboard on this app shows up when the virtual keyboard is disabled and seems to override it when it is enabled.

Comment: Dustin, did you find a solution for this? We have the exact same problem, with the app only receiving parts of the barcodes scanned - while the scanner works fine outside the app. Haven't tested with or without the keyboard yet, but we also need manual input...

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why the virtual keyboard may not appear if a scanner is attached is that the most common mode to run a scanner in (and IIRC the only way to use on on iOS) is in HID mode-  where it pretends its a hardware keyboard and sends key codes to the OS.  The OS will usually not display a virtual keyboard if a hardware one is attached.

Its possible to override this setting as the keyboard, by overriding onEvaluateInputViewShown.  From the app, all I can think of to do is force the keyboard to show with inputMethodManager.showSoftInput.

I haven't ever seen a scanner not send data because of a keyboard being up.  I have seen a scanner send data very slowly and take several seconds to send a small amount of characters.  I'd make sure you weren't just seeing a delay.

Comment: Hmm, it could very well be a delay. The scanner shows the code that was just read, and what is received in the app is often missing the last 1-3 characters of what is shown on the scanners display. I do occasionally get the full code even with the virtual keyboard enabled. Maybe the device reads the data out of order? The scanner always sends data, but the data isn't always received in full. I don't think it's a problem with the scanner itself, but on the receiving of the data.